# Dump to terminal or file content of "less" pager utility

Tags: terminal, less, pager

It is usual to use `less` utility as pager (with `-r` option).

But `less` uses special terminal buffers, so it preserve previous output to terminal and when I leave `less` I see previous content.

That is fine, but sometimes it is desired to append `less` content to terminal.

How can I configure `less` or what built-in command allow this?

If `less` doesn't allow this are there any pager capable to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in current `less` implementation. I wrote a letter to author with corresponding suggestion (see http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html#mail).

Very inconvenient workaround exist: press <kbd>s</kbd> key and enter a *file name*.